# In MVC is there a way to force a user off of a website if they have not done anything for a period of time starting from when they entered the w?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, model-view-controller, profiles

Can I use session timeouts to do this? Online, a lot of people use the word postback, but I know postbacks don't exist in MVC.

I also heard of user profile timeouts, but I cannot find any info about when the time duration before the timeouts occurs.

I really want to avoid using javascript or JQuery.

Comment: So where do you want to send users - to Google or back to where they came from?

Comment: try using this http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-mint.htm its a jquery timeout plugin. if the page is idle for a certain period of time, it starts displaying the timeout and if there is still no activity it will sign you out.

Comment: CodeRunner: back to google